# Error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10

Tags: date, java-8, java-time, parse-error, localdate

I´m trying to pase the next String using LocalDateTime, but I always get de unparsed text found error:

```
Error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-08-18 14:27:15.103+02' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

Here is my String: convertDate: '**2016-08-18 14:27:15.103+02**'

And my code:

```
public static LocalDate conversorStringToLocalDateTime(String convertDate) throws ParseException {
    LocalDate dateTime =LocalDate.parse(convertDate);
    return dateTime;
}
```

I guess is not too complicated, buy I´m not able to see the error. Could the **+02** in the String be the cause?

Comment: I think is the space between the date and time. Is that a space char or a non-breaking space? If your string comes from a form of some sort, that may be a different char than a space

Comment: It comes from a Postgre Database

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( "2016-08-18 14:27:15.103+02" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX" ) ) ;
```

## Details

The [Answer by greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39034181/642706) is correct about the problem (using a date-only object for a date-time value) but not the solution.

That Answer uses [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) which unnecessarily throws away valuable information about the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a specific moment on the timeline, only a vague idea about possible moments depending on adjusting into a particular time zone.

The `+02` is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) meaning “two hours ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)”. So in UTC the time-of-day for this simultaneous moment is 12 hours, 2 hours less than your 14 hours. This *does* represent a specific moment on the timeline. This offset is the valuable information you are throwing away with a `LocalDateTime` rather than an `OffsetDateTime`.

The format of your string is in SQL format, which is close to standard ISO 8601 format. Merely replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2016-08-18 14:27:15.103+02";
String inputModified = input.replace ( " " , "T" );
```

Unfortunately, Java 8 has a bug in parsing offset values abbreviated to just an hour or offset values omitting the colon between hours and minutes. Fixed in Java 9. But in Java 8, we need to adjust the input.

```
// Workaround for Java 8 where 2-digit offset fails parsing. Fixed in Java 9.
int lengthOfAbbreviatedOffset = 3;
if ( inputModified.indexOf ( "+" ) == ( inputModified.length () - lengthOfAbbreviatedOffset ) ) {
    // If third character from end is a PLUS SIGN, append ':00'.
    inputModified = inputModified + ":00";
}
if ( inputModified.indexOf ( "-" ) == ( inputModified.length () - lengthOfAbbreviatedOffset ) ) {
    // If third character from end is a PLUS SIGN, append ':00'.
    inputModified = inputModified + ":00";
}
```

Now parse.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( inputModified );
```

Dump to console. Note how we transformed `+02` into `+02:00`.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | inputModified: " + inputModified + " | odt: " + odt );
```

> input: 2016-08-18 14:27:15.103+02 | inputModified: 2016-08-18T14:27:15.103+02:00 | odt: 2016-08-18T14:27:15.103+02:00

Alternatively, specify a formatting pattern. The offset-parsing bug does not bite when using this formatting pattern.

```
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX" );
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

## Database

Coming from [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org), you should be retrieving the value as a date-time object rather than a String.

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 you can call `ResultSet::getObject` to get an `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. If not, call `ResultSet::getTimestamp` to get a `java.sql.Timestamp`, then immediately convert to java.time by calling `toInstant` on the Timestamp object.

Stick with java.time for your business logic; use the java.sql types briefly and only for exchange with the database.

Answer (score 17):

Your code is using `LocalDate` which only parses a date - not a date and time so you are getting an error when the parse finds the space after the date.

So you should be using `LocalDateTime` but `LocalDateTime.parse(String)` expects an ISO format date which is not the format you are using.

So you need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` to specify the format of your input string. Something like:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(convertDate, format);
```

Comment: Yes!!! That worked!!! I had tried also using LocalDateTime before , but with the worng DateTimeFormatter. Thanx :)