# SimpleDateFormat issue when parsing a String in ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, date, iso8601

Appreciate there are lots of similar posts on this but I couldn't find a specific one to help.

I'm trying to convert this string to a Date in Java

> 2017-05-16 06:24:36-0700

But it fails each time with this code

```
Date Login = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").parse("2017-05-16 06:24:36-0700");
```

Now I'm presuming its due to the timezone info at the end - I just can't figure out how to set the format. I tried this but no luck

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I suggest going here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone?rq=1

Comment: Your date has year-month-day with hyphens between and you try to parse it with a format that has the opposite order, day-month-year, and slashes instead of hyphens?

Comment: As far as I recall, the one-argument `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` would ignore any extra characters at the end of the string, like your time zone. So I doubt that its presence is your issue.

Comment: Similar Question: [Error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39033525/642706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The date format passed to your `SimpleDateFormat` is `"dd/MM/yy"`, while the date you are trying to parse is of the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. Try this instead:

```
Date login = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ").parse("2017-05-16 06:24:36-0700");
```

---

As a side note, depending on which version of Java you are using, I would recommend using the new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package (JDK 1.8+) or the [back port](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) of that package (JDK 1.6+) instead of the outdated (no pun intended) `Date` and/or `Calendar` classes.

```
Instant login = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ").parse("2017-05-16 06:24:36-0700"));
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, I had passed the date in the wrong format. Rookie error...thanks for the pointer

Comment: In java.time, simpler to replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601. Then parse directly: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-05-16 06:24:36-0700".replace( " " , "T" ) )`

Comment: @BasilBourque, I could not get that to work in Java 8 (Text '2017-05-16T06:24:36-0700' could not be parsed at index 19). It needs a colon in the offset, `-07:00`. I think you’ve told us once that it works in Java 9, though.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes indeed, as I recall now, failing to parse the offset lacking a colon is a bug in Java 8, fixed in Java 9. See [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/WOyoN8).

Answer (score 3):

I have already upvoted [Bryan’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44003136/5772882) exactly because it includes and recommends the `java.time` solution. I need to add a few thoughts, though.

Your code, reviloSlater, throws away the time zone information (more precsely, zone offset information), I’m not sure I would dare do that from the outset. With `java.time` classes it’s more natural to include it, and it’s easy to discard at a later point when we are sure we don’t need it.

To parse with offset:

```
    OffsetDateTime loginOdt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-05-16 06:24:36-0700",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"));
```

To drop the time zone offset information

```
    LocalDateTime loginLdt = loginOdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

A `LocalDateTime` is a date and a time without any time zone or offset information. In this case of course we get

```
2017-05-16T06:24:36
```

Bryan’s `java.time` code too uses the time zone offset information from the string. Edit: after Bryan’s edit that code now works and gives us:

```
2017-05-16T13:24:36Z
```

This is the same point in time (`Instant.toString()` prints the time in UTC). Another way is, with the `OffsetDateTime` from before we can just do

```
    Instant login = loginOdt.toInstant();
```

`java.time` is loaded with possibilities.

Comment: FYI, related Question: [*Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43360852/642706)