# DateTimeParseException while trying to perform ZonedDateTime.parse

Tags: datetime, java-8, date

Using **Java 8u222**, I've been trying a silly operation and it incurs in an error that I'm not being able to fully understand. The line code:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-07-03T02:20:46+06:00[Asia/Qostanay]");
```

The error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2011-07-03T02:20:46+06:00[Asia/Qostanay]' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 25
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:582)
```

Using the same date (although the timezone could be incorrect, the intention is just testing here), I changed the square bracket's value and it works, I mean:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-07-03T02:20:46+06:00[Europe/Busingen]);
```

It works as expected, as well as other values such:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-07-03T02:20:46+06:00[Asia/Ulan_Bator]")
ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-07-03T02:20:46+06:00[SystemV/CST6CDT]")
```

I found some similar questions such as the one below, but not precisely the same usage that I'm trying / facing. 
[Error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033525/error-java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-could-not-be-parsed-unparsed-tex)

Does someone have an understanding of Java Date API to help me out to grasp what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Asia/Qostanay` is a zone which doesn't exist in the JDK8's list of timezones. [It was added later](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215981).

If you don't care about the location of the timezone then just splice the `[...]` part of the string off the end before parsing. Knowing that the time is `+06:00` is going to sufficient for almost all purposes.

Alternatively, upgrade to a more recent version of Java.

Comment: I wonder if [updating Java’s time zone database](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) would suffice (rather than upgrading to a newer Java version completely).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, it will. All that data at run-time comes from `tzdata`, which is what that tool refers to updating. Wasn't aware that this tool existed though, I've never needed to use it.